# How do I create an iOS SDK/library that allows in app purchases on partnering 3rd party apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I've looked into stackoverflow and have not found an answer. Hoping it is not a repost.

Anyway, I want to create an iOS SDK/library. This will be included by my partners in their 3rd party apps. With the consent of the partner app, I want to be able to ask the user if they want to make an in-app purchase. After paying apple's 30% I want 70% of that to somehow come under my control because my product serves as a natural central point from everyone's standpoint: users and app developers. If the amount the user pays is $1, then the $0.70 can be used to provide a pay as you go functionality. Think of food in a fish game, a pet game...you pay for food in one app, the user can use that food in more than one app. In this example, the pet game and fish game are created by 2 distinct app developers and I am not one of them; I only provide the SDK/library.

This is not the real use case and the fish/pet food analogy only goes so far. For example, why can't they each charge $0.99 and not rely on a 3rd party like me? Let's just say, for business reasons, they are unable to.

Hopefully this is clear, and someone can help me out by providing a direct solution, or a workaround. Or tell me that this is not possible for sure. Happy to take pointers instead of full solutions.

Comment: No you can't. This violates Apple's In-App Purchase rules. Split the bill yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Raptor. Assuming the money will go to the app and not me, the SDK provider, is it possible for the SDK to initiate that payment flow, even if the money goes to the app developer. And will I get notification of that flow completing or aborting?

Comment: If you use the In-App Purchase (IAP) flow, there are delegate callbacks for completing / aborting the flow.